# create a simple two dimensinal array from unknown depth array

Tags: php

I have unknown depth of array but i want to make simple two dimensional array as following , earlier i think my question doesn't make exact sense so i edited this , please help

```
private function arrayDepth($a) {
$arr = array();
foreach ($a as $key => $val) {
    if (is_array($val)) {
        $this->arrayDepth($val);
     }
        else  {           
            $arr[] = $a;
        }           
    }       

}
```

my current array is

```
 Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [0] => 41
                [uid] => 41
                [1] => 16
                [pid] => 16
                [2] => 30
                [oid] => 30
                [3] => 1
                [value] => 1
                [4] => 0
                [optval] => 0
                [5] => 2014-05-26 16:41:31
                [updateDate] => 2014-05-26 16:41:31
            )

        [1] => Array
            (
                [0] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => 42
                        [uid] => 42
                        [1] => 16
                        [pid] => 16
                        [2] => 31
                        [oid] => 31
                        [3] => 1
                        [value] => 1
                        [4] => 0
                        [optval] => 0
                        [5] => 2014-05-26 16:45:49
                        [updateDate] => 2014-05-26 16:45:49
                    )

                [1] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => 44
                        [uid] => 44
                        [1] => 16
                        [pid] => 16
                        [2] => 31
                        [oid] => 31
                        [3] => 1
                        [value] => 1
                        [4] => 0
                        [optval] => 0
                        [5] => 2014-05-26 16:42:01
                        [updateDate] => 2014-05-26 16:42:01
                    )

                [2] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => 47
                        [uid] => 47
                        [1] => 16
                        [pid] => 16
                        [2] => 31
                        [oid] => 31
                        [3] => 1
                        [value] => 1
                        [4] => 0
                        [optval] => 0
                        [5] => 2014-05-26 16:45:19
                        [updateDate] => 2014-05-26 16:45:19
                    )

                [3] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => Array
                            (
                                [0] => 51
                                [uid] => 51
                                [1] => 16
                                [pid] => 16
                                [2] => 32
                                [oid] => 32
                                [3] => 1
                                [value] => 1
                                [4] => 0
                                [optval] => 0
                                [5] => 2014-05-26 16:47:27
                                [updateDate] => 2014-05-26 16:47:27
                            )

                    )

            )

    )
```

)

i need my output like all array which contain some  value into a single array like

```
array(
     [0] => Array
            (
                [0] => 41
                [uid] => 41
                [1] => 16
                [pid] => 16
                [2] => 30
                [oid] => 30
                [3] => 1
                [value] => 1
                [4] => 0
                [optval] => 0
                [5] => 2014-05-26 16:41:31
                [updateDate] => 2014-05-26 16:41:31
            )
            [1] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => 42
                        [uid] => 42
                        [1] => 16
                        [pid] => 16
                        [2] => 31
                        [oid] => 31
                        [3] => 1
                        [value] => 1
                        [4] => 0
                        [optval] => 0
                        [5] => 2014-05-26 16:45:49
                        [updateDate] => 2014-05-26 16:45:49
                    )

                [2] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => 44
                        [uid] => 44
                        [1] => 16
                        [pid] => 16
                        [2] => 31
                        [oid] => 31
                        [3] => 1
                        [value] => 1
                        [4] => 0
                        [optval] => 0
                        [5] => 2014-05-26 16:42:01
                        [updateDate] => 2014-05-26 16:42:01
                    )   ...... and so on  .....
```

Comment: Have you tried "return $arr;" ?

Comment: Final value of the full array or last item still in the array?

Comment: Is this one function or should there be two? Either way, using a recursive function without returning anything will not do anything. Unless you start deleting rows of course...

Comment: i tried return $arr but it return only single repeated value of array but i need to return complete array after loop

Comment: Your loop is incorrect. you need to check `is_array()` **BEFORE** you try to loop on the passed-in value. Your code will try to foreach the "final" scalar value you find at the "bottom" of the array.

Comment: @Marc B actually this is unknown depth of array so loop is right

Comment: no, it's not. it should be `if (is_array()) { foreach(...) }`. when you reach that "bottom" array, you'll call `$this->arrayDepth()` with a non-array value, and immediately foreach that.

Comment: please check edited question with output

Answer (score 0, accepted):

so finally i solved this issue, if you guys have any better solution please provide

```
function arrayDepth($a,&$arr) {
        foreach ($a as $key => $val) {
        if(is_array($val))
        if (is_array(@$val[0])) {
            arrayDepth($val,$arr);
        }
        else  {             
            $arr[] = $val;
     }      
      }     
}
arrayDepth($aNonFlat,$arr); 
var_dump($arr);
```